# Triggered for every new email in Inbox, Getting by IMAP

Tags: php, email, imap, zoho

I write a script, which scrape data from an email inbox. Now it works fine when I run on browser.
I want to run this script for every New email in that inbox. Auto run could be complete by CronJob. But in my server there is limitation on Cron, which is 30 mins, which is too long for me.

How could I do this ?  I need to run that script for every new Emails.

Here is my IMAP code in PHP

```
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Email: ' . imap_last_error());
/* grab UNSEEN emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
```

Comment: Use a daemon?  Use another language which is not web focused?  Install a filter in your SMTP server so it runs when the message is received rather than using IMAP?